# Showing a solution exists for a two-dimensional Cauchy problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let y(t) = (y1(t), y2(t))^T and

A(t) = (a(t) b(t)

```
    c(t) d(t)).
```

A(t) is a 2x2 matrix with a,b,c,d all polynomials in t. Consider the two dimensional Cauchy problem y'(t) = A(t)y(t), y(0)=y0.

Show that a solution exists for all t>=0.

Give a general condition on the A(t) which ensures global existence.

Please could you help me with this question - I don't know what to do

Comment: can anyone help with this?

Comment: Continuity and boundedness of the matrix $A(t)$ for all $t\geq 0$ is enough to ensure that the solution is global.

Comment: what about the solution existing for $$t>0$$

Answer (score 0):

Look at the equivalent integral equation.

$y(t)=y_0+\int_0^tA(s)y(s)ds\Rightarrow\|y(t)\|\leq\|y_0\|+\max\|A(s)\|\int_0^t\|y(s)\|ds$.

Let $M=\displaystyle\max_{t\geq 0}\|A(s)\|$ and use Gronwall's inequality to get $\|x(t)\|\leq\|y_0\|e^{Mt}$. It follows from this estimate that the Euclidean norm of $u$ remains bounded on any compact subset of $[0, \infty)$.